# Return data with no whitespace

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.2. I am looking querying usernames with eloquent in order to create a unique profile page. The issue I am having is the usernames are returning with white space e.g. John Doe I need it to return with no white space like johndoe or JohnDoe. Thanks.

```
public function show($username)
{
    try
    {
        $user = str_replace(' ', '', User::wherename($username)->firstOrFail());
        dd($user);

    }
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
    {
        return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function on your `User` model that returns `name` without any spaces. Like so:

```
public function getNameWithoutSpaces() {
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $this->name);
}
```

This way you can get the name without spaces wherever needed without having to use the `str_replace` function all the time.

Comment: best answer, really best forgot about Accessors))) on models))

Comment: ```$user = User::where('name', $username)->getNameWithoutSpaces()->first();
            dd($user);```

This is what I have now but it say's call to undefined method.

Comment: You have to use this function on your model, not on the query builder. So what you should do is `User::where('name', $username)->first()->getNameWithoutSpaces()`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. It won't remove the space.

Comment: Try using `preg_replace`, this should get a better result. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can help -

```
str_replace(" ", "", "John Doe");
```

Or if there is multiple spaces (continuous) -

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', "John Doe");
```

Comment: When I get the dd back the null is gone however I just get ""

Comment: Try to print the value before the replacement

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

After discussion, I think you need to use [slugs](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable):

```
$user = User::findBySlug($username);
$name = $user->name;
```

In this case, you'll have two columns in your table: **name** ('John Doe', for example) and **slug** ('JohnDoe' or 'johndoe' or 'John_Doe' etc).

**Original answer**

If you want to remove spaces from the beginning and the end of a string, try to [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) them:

```
$userOriginal = User::where('name', $username)->first();
$user = trim($userOriginal->name);
```

To remove all spaces, use this:

```
$user= str_replace(' ', '', User::where('name', $username-)->first()->name);
```

Comment: When I get the dd back the null is gone however I just get ""

Comment: It seems your query doesn't return any user, so try to use my updated code. If `users` table has `name` column, it should work. Also doublecheck it by `dd($userOriginal)`;

Comment: It still is returning "" for me. The username in the database is John Doe exactly like that.

Comment: `first()` is Instance of Collection, how you can aplly trim??))) you apply trim on column `trim($userOriginal->column)` or I dont know this trick??))

Comment: @GarethFrazer, so what exactly columns do you have? `name`, `username` ...? It's just confusing. @Froxz, I've already updated it, please look carefully.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Trim removes space from End and Start of the string but he need also in the middle

Comment: @Froxz, that's why I have alternative with `str_replace`. Please read answers carefully.

Comment: The updated code returns ''Trying to get property of non-object''

Comment: Ok, it seems your query returns nothing (null). I've asked you about your table structure, without this information noone will give you 100% working code.

Comment: The column name is name

Comment: Ok, but then why are you trying to hit database if you already have `$username` which is `name`?

Comment: ```$username``` is what I pass into the url and then it looks for the name in the users table as I am looking to set up profiles for each user.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to use slugs, pease read update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::wherename($username)->first();
if($user){
  $user_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $user->name); //or other column that you need to clean
  return dd($user_name);
} 
return 'No user found!';
```

Comment: It returns no user found however when I put a space in the url it will return the user.

Comment: If no user found then you have to check your `$username` parameter that you pass in url!

Comment: Say for example I pass in johndoe. It returns null. How do I ensure that what I'm passing is able to match up to the records e.g. I pass johndoe will it find John Doe?

Comment: @GarethFrazer to do that You have to ensure first, when you save Data to DB. so you save them with Whitespaces or No.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::wherename($username)->first()

$UserName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $user->name);
print_r($UserName );die;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define getter on your user model

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $this->attribute['name'])
}
```

After that when you try get `$user->name`, it always be without spaces.